# How I can inspect the elements that appear while mouse click, disappear while mouse leave

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I want to inspect the YouTube settings menu element in chrome-developer with c# selenium.

The YouTube settings menu element appears on mouse click, but disappears if the mouse is moved out, so I cannot inspect the element in chrome-developer.

Any ideas?

Comment: The YouTube setting menu disappears when I click on chrome inspector tool. I could not find a good way to stop it from disappearing but I can tell you the css class for the setting menu is **ytp-settings-menu**. Look for the div with class **ytp-settings-menu** in developer tool _Element_ tab and then _uncheck_ the _Style_ **display: none;**, you will be able to see the setting menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Preview]

1. Visual studio and Chrome Browser as half of the Width of window
2. Breakpoint after click
3. At chrome browser, press `F12` for inspect
4. We can find the settings dialog element in inspect tools area.
5. We must not click the **html body area(Red Area)** while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, then try the "Sources" tab, then go to the file you're trying to debug, then add line breakers. Next refresh the page. Here's an image of what we're looking for, inspected the google.com page for this one.

[image: Debugging with inspector]

Once you have reached the line break for the mouseclick on the debugging, you can go to the elements tab, it should have the elements currently paused on the screen.